# Qt/Qml 3D How to render a mesh from array of vertices

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

I am playing with generating meshes in runtime, although I've stucked on drawing a simple cube. Why nothing is appearing on the screen?

**How to turn a array of floats (triangle vertices) into 3D mesh?**

To meet the required description length, I have second, related question. When the cube will be already rendered, how to put a texture on it?

```
   class Master : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit Master(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent)
        {
            float vertexArray[] = {
                -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
                -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
                -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
                -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
                -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
                1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
                -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
                1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
                1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
                -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
                -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
               -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
                1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
                -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
                -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
                -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
                1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
                -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
                -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f
            };

            m_buffer.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(vertexArray), sizeof(vertexArray));
        }

        Q_PROPERTY(QByteArray buffer READ buffer CONSTANT)
        QByteArray buffer() const { return m_buffer; }

    private:
         QByteArray m_buffer;

    };
```

And the GeometryRenderer in Scene3D:

```
  Entity{
            Material{
                id: material
                parameters: [
                    Parameter { name: "color"; value: "green" }
                ]
            }

            GeometryRenderer{
                id: geometryRenderer

                instanceCount: 0
                primitiveType: GeometryRenderer.Triangles

                geometry: Geometry{
                    Attribute{
                        attributeType: Attribute.VertexAttribute
                        vertexBaseType: Attribute.Float
                        vertexSize: 3
                        byteOffset: 0
                        byteStride: 3 * 4
                        count: 12
                        buffer : Buffer{
                            type: Buffer.VertexBuffer
                            data: Master.buffer
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            components: [material, geometryRenderer]
        }
```

Comment: Your material is lacking everything you need to render. You need to add an effect, a technique, a render pass that also has the shader. Have a look at the source code of Qt3D's ready made materials to see how it's done. Or simply use one of those materials, eg phong material.

Comment: Thanks. I've resolved this on my own about a hour ago. The real problem is passing a QByteArray or QBuffer from c++ to Qml. When using Float32Array inside JS, I am able to render a shape.

Comment: Ah okay! But did you modify the material as well? I'm curious because I thought it shouldn't work this way ;) if you have solved something post an answer and accept it! This way other people can use this information as well.

Comment: I will, just need some time to order information in my head, and write a quick turoial here, how to generate a line, a triangle and how to deal with QByteArray from either c++ and js side.